# Express static behaviour

Tags: node.js, express

I have a server running with express. Let's say I have the following folder structure:

```
- public
-- image1.png
-- image2.png
-- image3.png

- src
-- app.js
```

In the app.js I setup the server using express and I do:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Now, If I start the server and go to localhost:port/image1.png I get image1.png displayed.

I am confused because the path I specified is incorrect, kinda. If I do:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public'))
```

I get the same result. Why they work the same?

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file and restarted the server? Also which Express version are you using?

Comment: I just checked again and the folder structure is the one described. I use express 4.

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on **"how you start your server"**

if you do:

`node src/app.js`

it will work because from a Node.js perspective, the path `public` exists in the file system from where the `node` process started,

now, if you do:

```
cd src
node app.js
```

it will not work because there's no `public` folder in the file system from where the `node` process started

behind the scenes, Express.js is using the [`serve-static`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/) package,

if you look in the source code, it is using `path.resolve` to load the folder:

https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L65

and looking at the [Node.js documentation for `path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths), we have:

**"If no path segments are passed, path.resolve() will return the absolute path of the current working directory."**

So, resolving `public` from the current working directory of `node` when using `node src/app.js`, the folder exists!

that's why it works! :)